# Getting Values of Replace Elements in an External List

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, save

I have a list of elements replaced with values:
`list = {A-> A1, B-> B1, C-> C1,...}` saved as an external file using `Save`. I use `<< list` to get the entire list:

```
<<list
list = {A-> A1, B-> B1, C-> C1,...}
```

I need to get certain element values. For example, I would like to use something like `<< A` and get `A1` and so on. How can I do that?

Comment: You could convert to an `Association[]`...

Comment: @J.M. How would this help?

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {A -> A1, B -> B1, C -> C1};
file = "C:\\list.txt";
Export[file, list];
list2 = ReadList[file];
A /. list2
```

or this one may help

```
list3 = FindList[file,"A"];
A /. list3
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather not read the entire list. I would like to get single values at a time.

Comment: @Bran try FindList.